# adding column to a list in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, append

I am trying to add a column to a list where the elements are already being appended. Have seen similar questions on stack, but none seem to solve the issue.

Below is what i am trying to do:
There is a list of words, and another series of text. i want to select all the texts that contain any of the words in the 'words' list. Have gotten the texts containing any of the words from the list, but i also want to associate the respective words with the particular text.
code so far:

```
com=[]
for t in text.c:
    for w in words:
        if w in t:
            com.append(t)
            com = com + [w]
```

currently it adds the wth word in a different column, below the text. How can i add a column so that the respective word is added in a different column but same row?
com is a list.

```
Eg:

text:
     c
0    this is good
1    You can improve more photos
2    development is required
3    keep up the good word
4    add more pics from different angles
5    add more good photos
6    this is not good for you

words=['good','photos']

required output:

0    this is good                 good
1    You can improve more photos  photos
2    keep up the good word        good
3    add more good photos         good
4    add more good photos         photos 
5    this is not good for you     good
```

Comment: can you post desired input and expected output

Comment: @ Hackaholic, @ Vignesh Kalai: have added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: What if all words are present are you expecting all words to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached to the above output by using a function: namedtuple()

The function can be used as:

```
Lang = namedtuple("Lang", ("word", "c"))
com=[]
for f in c:
    for w in words:
        if w in f:
            com.append(Lang(w,f))

output: 
0    this is good                 good
1    You can improve more photos  photos
2    keep up the good word        good
3    add more good photos         good
4    add more good photos         photos 
5    this is not good for you     good
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a func that takes the text and returns the matches:

```
In [126]:
words=['good','photos']
def func(x):
    found=[]
    for word in words:
        if word in x:
            found.append(word)
    if len(found) > 0:
        return found

df['found'] = df['c'].apply(func)
df

Out[126]:
                                         c           found
index                                                     
0                             this is good          [good]
1              You can improve more photos        [photos]
2                  development is required            None
3                    keep up the good word          [good]
4      add more pics from different angles            None
5                     add more good photos  [good, photos]
6                 this is not good for you          [good]
```